# How to combine multiple activity data like Facebook with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, facebook, android-activity, feed, linkedin-api

I have made a search but couldn't find a solution which works for me.

I just wonder how Facebook or Linkedin manages to handle same type activity with one sentence?
I mean, if you store every activity with different IDs in an Activity Table, how can you list them as "Member_a and 15 more people changed their photos"

I'm trying to make a social activity wall for my web-site, it's not that big but I just wanted to know the logic on this situation.

For example, when first page loads, I make an Ajax call and listing 0-10 records and if user scrolls down, page makes another ajax call which lists 11-20 records.

Now; if I try to combine same type of activity after sql select query with using if else, if this 10 records are the same, the user will only see 1 item. I hope I could explain what I want to say :)

So, I need a solution which makes this query in SQL Statement.

I'm not asking from you to write a query for me, I just want to know the logic.

Here is a screenshot what I want to achieve:

[image]

[image]

You see, they are actually different stored data but they combined it and made it as a 1 item network update.

By the way, I'm using C# and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please provide information about your table structure. and anyway, these information don't have to be fetched in 1 query.

Comment: @Maziar Taheri - There is an Network_Feed table. feedID, feedType, memberID. Everytime a member changes his photo, a record is inserted in this table with memberID. if feedType is 1=photo upload so I want to list the members who changed their photos. The question is for example, 5 people changed their photo in the same order and I need to combine these same feedType records in one title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
SELECT Min(b.MemberName), COUNT(*) as Total FROM Network_Feed a
JOIN Member b on a.MemberID = b.MemberID
WHERE a.FeedType = 1
```

did I understand your question right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to manage petabytes of data as a one table. So, big projects running on SQL Server are used some advanced scaling(distributing data and load) tricks like Service Brokers and Replication.

You can check 
http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?CaseStudyID=4000004532 as an SQL Server example.

Comment: thanks (teşekkürler) @Yasar GOZUDELI but for now this is not a concern for us as we only have 30.000 members :) I just wanted to know the logic of this combining thing.